# Как сократить этот код?

Tags: java, android, инспекция-кода

Каким образом можно сократить этот код

```
if(acet_name.getText().length()==0&&acet_surname.getText().length()==0){
til_name.setErrorEnabled(true);
til_surname.setErrorEnabled(true);
til_name.setError("Обязательно для заполнения");
til_surname.setError("Обязательно для заполнения");
}
else if(acet_name.getText().length()==0){
til_name.setErrorEnabled(true);
til_name.setError("Обязательно для заполнения");
}
else     if(acet_surname.getText().length()==0){
til_surname.setErrorEnabled(true);
til_surname.setError("Обязательно для заполнения");
}
```

Сначала идёт проверка обоих `AppCompatEditText` на пустоту, а потом каждого по отдельности. Если сделать логическое ИЛИ `||`, то в любом случае нужно прописать проверку какой из них пуст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Удалить первый `if` полностью.
2. Удалить все `else`.

```
if(acet_name.getText().length() == 0) {
  til_name.setErrorEnabled(true);
  til_name.setError("Обязательно для заполнения");
}

if(acet_surname.getText().length() == 0) {
  til_surname.setErrorEnabled(true);
  til_surname.setError("Обязательно для заполнения");
}
```

Comment: Точняк, тупанул ))